# How to pass value to property that name was passed in function parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I'm getting eslint/typescript error:

```
errorUnsafe member access .value on an any value
@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
```

while i try to save value to dynamic property name:

```
selectChange(name: string, value: string) {
    if(this[name] && typeof this[name].value === "string") {
      this[name].value = value
    }
  }
```

I add if-statement, but it doesn't help, is it possible to do it in proper way ? Or i have to change eslint configuration file.

Comment: Does `this` has an index like `[index: string]: string;`?

Comment: @Anatoly nevermind, i have quick solution to a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have solution:

declare in some place above:

```
type column = 'property1' | 'property2'
```

and remove unnecesary if-statement from method:

```
selectChange(name: column, value: string) {
    this[name].value = value
}
```

And it will be working perfectly.